# Create different flavours of excerpt

Tags: filters, excerpt

I have an understanding problem with the Wordpress filter approach.

I thought that I could easily use something like `the_excerpt()` on one hand and create the `the_excerpt_function_for_this_special_page()` on the other hand. However, it turns that I'm really lost between the filters and functions and I do not know how to achieve my goal.

**What I want to build**

I added a filter to the `get_the_excerpt` filter as follows:

```
function the_readmore_excerpt( $excerpt ) { 
    return $excerpt. '.. <a class="read-more" href="'. get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '">' . __('Mehr lesen', 'baskerville') . ' &rarr;</a>'; 
} 

add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'the_readmore_excerpt');
```

That's working well except that it appears on **every** excerpt on the website (that's actually expected).

**Question**

How do I get 2 different excerpts: one with read more and one without (based on this code)?

Comment: on what condition should that choice be based? i.e. what would distinguish the two different excerpts?

Comment: @Michael I would call the `read more` in the `post-in-page-loop` from here https://github.com/ivycat/posts-in-page/blob/master/templates/posts_loop_template.php and the other would stay used by the system.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's not the best approach because it requires introducing a global variable but here's the idea:

In `Posts_in_Page` plugin there are 2 filters, one is fired before output of these items `posts_in_page_pre_loop`, and one after output end `posts_in_page_post_loop`. So the plan is to create global variable which will be set to `true` when you are in this plugin's loop and to `false` when it's outside, so in your excerpt filter you'll be able to check it.

So here's how it can be done:

```
/*
 * Sets our global flag that we are inside this plugin's specific loop. And returns content untouched.
 */
function my_custom_set_in_posts_pages_loop($output){

    global $custom_loop_is_in_posts_in_page_post_loop;
    $custom_loop_is_in_posts_in_page_post_loop = true;

    return $output; // output is untouched we return it as is, because we only switch our flag.
}
add_filter('posts_in_page_pre_loop', 'my_custom_set_in_posts_pages_loop');

/*
 * Sets our global flag that we are inside this plugin's specific loop. And returns content untouched.
 */
function my_custom_set_out_of_posts_pages_loop($output){
    global $custom_loop_is_in_posts_in_page_post_loop;
    $custom_loop_is_in_posts_in_page_post_loop = false;

    return $output; // output is untouched we return it as is, because we only switch our flag.
}
add_filter('posts_in_page_post_loop', 'my_custom_set_out_of_posts_pages_loop');


function the_readmore_excerpt( $excerpt ) {
    global $custom_loop_is_in_posts_in_page_post_loop;

    if( isset($custom_loop_is_in_posts_in_page_post_loop) && $custom_loop_is_in_posts_in_page_post_loop ){
        return $excerpt. '.. <a class="read-more" href="'. get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '">' . __('Mehr lesen', 'baskerville') . ' &rarr;</a>';
    }

    return $excerpt; // return default excerpt if we are not in this custom plugin's loop.
}

add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'the_readmore_excerpt');
```

Again it's probably not a perfect solution because of introducing a global variable, but it will work.

Plugin's filters hooks are got from here https://github.com/ivycat/posts-in-page/blob/master/includes/class-page-posts.php (lines 364, 373)